# responsive design with bootstrap not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to append a Search button to an input search field which is not working properly.

I am not able to trace the error as I am new to bootstrap.

I have set up an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azF8w/52/)

I am trying to make it work in an asp.net webform based website

Below is the code snippet

```
        <div id="search-wrapper" class="span3 offset5">
            <div  class="span3 input-append">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch"  placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Go!" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

`Go` Button doesn't append properly with the input field. as shown in this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms)

I have made some minor changes to css to make it work with max-width:1000px.

Rest is almost same. I even tried to use botstrap css directly from CDN but it doesnt make different to the button

UPDATE:

I tried changing `.btn` css

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *border-left: 0 none #e6e6e6;
    border-right: 0 none #e6e6e6;
    border-top: 0 none #e6e6e6;
    border-bottom: 0 none #b3b3b3;
    display: inline;
    padding: 4px 12px;
```

This line to  padding: 6px 12px;. This minutely fixed it in FF but other browser it make problem worse.

Comment: You aren't using the add-on class required for input prepend.

Comment: What changes did you do to your BootStrap css (which classes exactly did you modify)? Did you set the `border` attributes to `0 none`?

Comment: I didnt made any change to Border I just added `.Container {max-width:1000px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Works here, a bit of a bad design: http://jsfiddle.net/azF8w/54/

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on"><button>Go</button></span>
  <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

Comment: As i said i am new to boostrap you can say i am learning. So i am not sure how this is a bad design & how i can fix this as it renders differently in FF, Chrome & IE

Comment: It works absolutely fine on Google Chrome. Well, the button can be designed to match the add-on colors but it does work. Check it out, oh and the buttons will show up differently on varying rendering engines.

Comment: If that is the case then why does this page render problem in different browsers http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Comment: I must repeat that is using ASP.net webforms

Comment: What do you mean it "render problem in different browsers" ?

Comment: Okay, it is using ASP.net, we get that, how does that relate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35439/discussion-between-ali-gajani-and-knowledgeseeker)